# Pull data from specific div on external site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Okay, I've seen a lot of topics hovering around this theme, but all of them I've seen involve JSON or Ajax to respond to client-side events. I don't need to do that. I just want to load data from a specific div on an external site when my page loads.

For example, say an external site `http://www.example.site` has the following code:

```
<div id="tm_score_1">
    129.5
</div>
```

When my own page loads, I want to be able to pull in that `129.5` value. I'm assuming it isn't as simple as using `load("http://www.example.site #tm_score_1")` because it's an external site, right?

Comment: Correct, since it is an external site, you will have to get the html from the site using php on your server, Or you will have to retrieve it using YQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what Tentonaxe was saying about retrieving it from your server.
The idea is to have a path like

```
________      ________        __________
|      |     |        |      | external |
| user |     | server |      |   site   |
|______| ->  |________|  ->  |__________|
\......\     |........|      /........../
 \______\    |________|     /__________/

     \/-----<----<
                 ^ 
Javascript ->   PHP    ->  Retrieve Info -\/
                 ^<--------<--------<------
```

The idea is your javascript calls php on *your* server, which then uses curl or file_get_contents to connect to the external server and retrieve the information.  This information is then passed back to the javascript from the php on your server.

(and yes, I was bored enough to do some (admittedly bad) ascii art for it).

Comment: I love me some good ascii art. But since I want to load the data when my page loads, I don't actually need to involve js at all, do I?

Comment: Nope, just add a `file_get_contents` in some php on the page load, and that should do it.

Comment: Thanks. Pressing my luck, do you have a handy regex to parse the content within my target <div> once I pull in the page?

Comment: Maybe look at: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/, with something like `$num = $article->find('div#tm_score_1', 0)->plaintext`

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this in javascript because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), without some server-side proxy.  You could either proxy it on your server or use a proxy provided by someone else, like Yahoo (as suggested by other answers) via [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) or YQL via this [plugin](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/).

Comment: Figured, thanks. But the above (pull data out of a div on another site) is possible via, say, PHP then?

Comment: @praguian - yes, you could make a query on the server to the web site in question, parse the response, and put that data on your page.  you could even have a php script that you call from your page that does that.  seems like it might be unethical or even illegal, tho, unless the site that you're scaping gives permission to do so or you attribute the content to them.

Comment: Added info below about using Yahoo's server's as a proxy

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [cross domain jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/).

You then can do the following using yahoo's server as a proxy.

```
$('#container').load('http://google.com'); // SERIOUSLY!

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://news.bbc.co.uk',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var headline = $(res.responseText).find('a.tsh').text();
        alert(headline);
    }
});
```

James Padolsey blogged about it [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

If the robots.txt permits, you could use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/). Here's a query for the [current version of jQuery](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=use%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fyqlblog.net%2Fsamples%2Fdata.html.cssselect.xml%27%20as%20data.html.cssselect%3B%20select%20%2a%20from%20data.html.cssselect%20where%20url%3D%22www.yahoo.com%22%20and%20css%3D%22%23news%20a%22#h=use%20%27http%3A//yqlblog.net/samples/data.html.cssselect.xml%27%20as%20data.html.cssselect%3B%20select%20%2a%20from%20data.html.cssselect%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//jquery.com/%22%20and%20css%3D%22.jq-version%22).